# How can we add Firebase Crashlytics in flutter where the flutter app is itself added to existing iOS and Android app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics, flutter-add-to-app

I want to add a flutter app into my existing native app, which I am able to do succesfully using flutter [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app). After this, I want to log crashes and other data using firebase for the flutter screens. Since normal implementation of Flutter Fire requires changes to be made in the android and iOS folders, but these folders do not exist in flutter project. So any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: There is an ios and android folder in evert flutter project

Comment: Yes @YouriLieverdink , but when we create a flutter module, these folder are  Generated folders which are not be source controlled, and also they have mentioned in the doc as to not make any changes in these folders as the changes might be overwritten by flutter

Comment: Could you provide a link to where this is mentioned?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#module-organization Read the note here, same for Android

Comment: Oh my mistake. The only thing I can think of is to implement Crashlytics for both iOS and Android separately.

Comment: That is already there, but how can I assure that any crash which happens inside flutter module is caught on Firebase?

Comment: You can add this line to your main function to record all uncaught flutter errors. 
//
FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;

Comment: To even include firebase, the changes have to be made to the iOS and Android folders, but doing so is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I solved by this way:

1. Don't put changes in ios and android folder.
2. Use callback to send your crash information by the native side.
3. Configure FarebaseCrashlytics only in native app.

For example:

Native side in Swift:

```
let methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "FLUTTER_CHANNEL", binaryMessenger: flutterEngine.binaryMessenger)
                methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
                    if call.method == "HANDLE_ERROR" {
                        let userInfo: [String: String] = [
                            "deviceId": UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
                        ]
                        var errorData = "";
                        if let args = call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                            errorData = args["data"] as? String ?? ""
                        }

                        let error = NSError(domain: errorData, code: 0, userInfo: userInfo)

                        Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
                    }
                }
```

Flutter side:

```
   Future<void> _handleErrorNative([String errorData]) async {
    try {
      final methodChannel = MethodChannel("FLUTTER_CHANNEL");
      await methodChannel.invokeMethod(
        'HANDLE_ERROR',
        {
          "data": errorData,
        },
      );
    } on PlatformException catch (_) {
      print("_handleErrorNative PlatformException");
    }
  }
```

Remember, the crash only will send after reopen the app.

Comment: What does the errorData variable contain?